# get value tables in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

I have a project with to table (Student and Course) and a relational table StudentCourse :

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
@JoinTable(
        name = "StudentCourse",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "studentid") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "courseid") }
)
```

now I want to give value of this table and join it to another table . but it dosen't work . help me please. and i want to know is that any other way better than this work that i do .....this is my code for this work :

```
 public static List<Course> getSelectedCurse() throws SQLException {
   yourstcode = Console.getInputInteger("enter your code");
   Session session = OpenSession1();
   List<Course> courses = session.createNamedQuery("SELECT coursename FROM Course where id in (SELECT courseid from StudentCourse WHERE studentid=" + yourstcode + "").list();
   CloseSession(session);
   return courses;
}
```

//courseid and coursecode are my foreign key that refer to id in Course and Student table

Comment: You need no query at all for that purpose. If you have defined well the relationship in the entities, you only have to access the member in Student that contains all its courses. Hibernate will launch the join query for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think it's not working because you are using createNamedQuery method.
use createQuery if you are using JPQL syntax or createNativeQuery if you want to use pure sql syntax.

Comment: You need no specific query at all if the entities has established the relationship. Just recover the student and traverse its courses. Your answer is very vague.

Comment: @RubioRic yes but information of student save in one table and information of courses save in another table and i have a table for many to many relation that save just foreign keys . for show name of course that student selected i should give student id from StudentCourse and then for this id show lessons that he take . with recover student i can't do that

Comment: @reihane Yes, you can. It's one of the goals of an ORM like Hibernate. You are thinking in terms of tables and you should think in terms of java entities. In Student you have (or should have) a list of Courses. If you recover an specific Student from DB, you can acess his list of courses. Hibernate does recover them for you.

Comment: @reihane You need to study a bit more about Hibernate principles. "Java Persistence with Hibernate Second Edition" by Christian Bauer, Gavin King (One of the founders of Hibernate) et al is a good book. It may be a bit outdated in relation with the latest versions but all the principles are there.